# Read EXIF data from NSImage

Tags: swift, image, macos, core-graphics

I have a swift macOS application that I have been using to read EXIF metadata from photos on disk. This is working well using the following snippet

```
let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilename.path)
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(photoURL,nil) {
        if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {// Grab all of the properties ! replaced with ?
            if let exifDict = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]
```

I now want to be able to read EXIF data from an NSImage that is stored in my  applications assets

I have the code that can access the image

```
let myphoto = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name(rawValue: "myPhoto"))
```

I just can't work out how to bridge between the NSImage and get a CGImageSource so I can access the EXIF dictionary